How can I parse a .ini file with this type of format?
I would like to parse a generated .ini file containing some config parameters, but I am a little uncertain of the format used. I am not able to change the format of the generated .ini file. This is a snippet of what the format looks like:
[Sensors]
Sensors = {
    (
        [0]={
            SensorType=Camera
            Refresh=30
        }
    )}

I am able to access the Sensors variable with the following code:
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
path = "my_config.ini"
config.read(path)
single_sensor = config["Sensors"]["Sensors"]
print(single_sensor)

Output:
{
(
[0]={
SensorType=Camera
Refresh=30
}
)}

The problem is that this is a string that I can not parse further the same way. Let's say I want to access SensorType. Then the following syntax would not work:
single_sensor = config["Sensors"]["Sensors"]["0"]["SensorType"]

So how could I go about parsing a .ini file in this format? Would I have to parse the string separately after retrieving what I can using the .ini section syntax?

The built-in configparser cannot of course support every config format imaginable. It is common to write your own parser for such custom format.

You could try something like the following, whereby you should type your business logic under the get - function.
from configparser import ConfigParser

class CustomConfigParser(ConfigParser):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, section, option, *, raw=False, vars=None, fallback=None):
        value = super().get(section, option, raw=raw, vars=vars, fallback=fallback)
        # Add custom parsing logic here
        
        # the returned value should be something like the following :
        # return value
        return {"SensorType":"Camera",
                "Refresh":30}
        

config = CustomConfigParser() 
path = "my_config.ini" 
config.read(path)
single_sensor = config["Sensors"]["Sensors"]
print(single_sensor)

print(single_sensor["SensorType"])

>>>{'SensorType': 'Camera', 'Refresh': 30}
>>>Camera

